# How to get the value of a particular input field using id in the html templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div html elements with different id and here I am using spinner. Whenever values in the spinner input changes alert box will be displayed.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="accordion2" class="panel-group" style="display: block;">  
    <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
        <div id="Tea">
            <div class="spinner Tea input-group ">
                <input type="text"  id = "servings" class="form-control input-    sm"  value="Tea"/>
                <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                        <button class="btn Tea btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn Tea btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <h4 id="energy" class="Tea"> Tea </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="Coffee">
                <div class="spinner Coffee input-group ">
                    <input type="text"  id = "servings" class="form-control input-sm"  value="Coffee"/>
                    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                        <button class="btn Coffee btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn Coffee btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <h4 id="energy" class="Coffee">Coffee</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQuery code**

```
$(function(){
    $('.spinner:first-of-type input').on('click', function() {
        $('.spinner:first-of-type input').val(parseInt($('.spinner:first-of-type input').val(), 10) + 1);
        var val = $('.spinner:first-of-type input').val(); 
        changeValues(val);
    });
    $('.spinner:last-of-type input').on('click', function() {  
        $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);  
    });   

    function changeValues(value){
        alert($('#energy').attr('class').split(' '));
    };

});
```

But in the alert box whenever I click the spinner up arrow only Tea is displayed.
what I expect is when the spinner is clicked from Tea div tea should be displayed and when from coffee , coffee should be displayed.Please help me out

Comment: for ids use #idofelement as selector

Comment: you have duplicated ids they have to be unique use name (or class instead) and use the related selector.

Comment: Having just edited the whitespace in your html, it looks like you're missing a closing `div` somewhere, I assume for the #Tea `div`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally got what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that you want to increment and decrement number of beverage cups on up/down buttons click. For this you would better modify mark up a little (remove duplicated ids, add classes for convenience). And I may look like this then:

```
$(function() {
    $('.spinner').on('click', '.servings', function(e) {
        $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10) + 1);
        var val = $(this).val();
        changeValues.call(e.delegateTarget, val);
    })
    .on('click', '.up', function(e) {
        $(e.delegateTarget).find('.servings').val(function() {
            return ++this.value;
        });
    })
    .on('click', '.down', function(e) {
        var $input = $(e.delegateTarget).find('.servings');
        if (+$input.val() > 1) {
            $input.val(function() {
                return --this.value;
            });
        }
    });

    function changeValues(value) {
        var type = $(this).find('.energy').data('type');
        alert(type);
    };
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9vXC0RipxkzqhXrHJAKD?p=preview

Comment: Too much DOM traversing and errors. If `$(this).val() === 'some string'` then `parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10) === NaN` and this too `+$input.val()`

Comment: You solution also has as much errors as mine (-3 cups). Also `$buttons.eq(0)` is a serious flaw ;). so we are even. But in general answering such questions is not worth it, too much unclear. So I'm going to remove my answer, since I don't like it myself. But if you can improve yours I would upvote because your code is a little cleaner indeed.

Comment: Whats wrong with `$buttons.eq(0)`? From official documentation: `eq(index)` index: An integer indicating the 0-based position of the element. I use it because source html markup is not allow to use clean selectors (better way)

Comment: Nothing wrong with `eq()`. The problem is that your code will not work if you change markup, maybe add some new buttons. That's why I added classes `.up` and `.down`. I think that changing markup to make it better is not forbidden, to remove duplicated ids, for example.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.spinner').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),            
            $buttons = $el.find('button'),
            $h4 = $el.find('h4'),
            input = $el.find('input').get(0);

        function showAlert() {
            alert($h4.get(0).className);
        }

        $buttons.eq(0).on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0) + 1;

            showAlert();
        });

        $buttons.eq(1).on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0) - 1;
        });       
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/yLtn57aw/2/

Hope this helps